# App store submission - new release list

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is not code related but it is an issue I am having with an iPhone app.

I submitted two apps (separate binaries), one for iphone , one for ipad. They had slightly different names and screenshots but the same icon graphics. The two apps were approved by Apple but only the iPad version got listed in the "see all" list in its catagory in iTunes. 
I am wondering why the iphone version did not appear in the counterpart list.

My question is, is it something I have done or something apple has done?

Comment: Perhaps it's an iTunes setting?

Comment: no i looked in both the ipad and iphone versions. they are effectively two apps